# Save ListViewColumns' widths to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I want to save ListViewColumns' widths to xml file.How to do ?

Comment: There's more than one question there, and the title is a bit obscure. If you're having trouble, try narrowing it down to "how to iterate through columns in a listview" to start with, and *post the code you've already written* as part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you can retrieve the column count like so:

```
int columnCount = listView.Columns.Count;
```

If you wish to iterate over the columns you can do the following:

```
foreach (ColumnHeader column in listView.Columns)
{
    //Use the column.Width Property to get the width and save it to XML.
}
```

Look into using the XmlDocument class  or Linq to XML, to persist and load your XML data.

[XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

[LINQ to XML - 5 Minute Overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Answer (score 0):

So write multiple XML entries, identifying them by the column identifier. Is there something more complex in here?

Comment: I add columns dynamicly and i dont know anything about them.And want to when app run it restored old ListViewColumns' widths.and i dont know to save and restore to xml file

Answer (score 0):

A common way to express in XML uniform element collections without a fixed size is the following:

```
<columns>
  <column>one</column>
  <column>two</column>
  ...
</columns>
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: aha ,like that.but i dont how to write xml when ran project it restored correctly .